# Cannot RDP from Ubuntu to WS 2016 with Domain User

Tags: active-directory, rdp, ubuntu-16.04, windows-server-2016

Im trying to use Remmina to RDP from Ubuntu to Windows Server 2016. I think it's not a Remmina issue since i can RDP with Administrator but i cannot do it from domain users.

RDP CALs are installed ok, I know this because users can RDP without any problem from a Windows OS but cannot make it work with Remmina.

I need to migrate all the computers to work from Ubuntu via RDP with WS2016 but i need the RDP from the ubuntu to work... Hope you can help me.

I've already tried to uncheck **'Allow connections only from computers running Desktop with Network Level Authentication**

Comment: what is the error displayed?

Comment: Unable to connect RDP server x.x.x.x

Comment: are you connecting with domain prefix with both users? if not, perhaps try

Comment: although it sounds as Windows group policy issue

Answer (score 0):

Add someone to the list of allowed incoming RDP users.

System Properties > Remote > Select Users

Admin is there by default, but your other users are not.